# Visual Studio can't find .NET Core SDK?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015

I've got Visual Studio 2015 Professional installed, as well as what I *should* need to run and debug .NET Core code.  Those packages are:

Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 - SDK Preview 2 (x64)
Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 - SDK Preview 2 (x86)
Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2

When I try to open an existing .NET Core app that was developed on a Mac, I get the following error popup in Visual Studio:

[image: Visual Studio Failure Message]
When I run the `dotnet --version` command in `cmd.exe`, I get the following output:  `1.0.0-preview2-003121`.

Am I missing some version of something?  I've gone over a bunch of other posts that suggested that making sure that the DotNet CLI was uninstalled would fix this kind of problem, but I don't have it installed, and I'm still not able to get Visual Studio to correctly restore packages or build a .NET Core app.

**EDIT:**  Here are the contents of `project.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml": "5.0.0-beta8-305061149",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "AWSSDK.S3": "3.2.5-beta",
    "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions": "4.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of the SDK does the project.json call for?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio Update 3 ?

Comment: Yes, I installed Visual Studio Update 3 before trying all of this.

Comment: Maybe you can find this helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/1431833/visual-studio-2019-unable-to-locate-net-core-sdk. It worked for me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, repairing Visual Studio after making sure that the Core SDK was installed fixed my problem.  I guess I got things out of order when I was installing.